Lists With Generic Data Types In SwiftUI
I've written a simple list in SwiftUI that accepts a generic data type.
The goal was to make a reusable list where when an item was selected, the list would execute a callback with the selected data.
I struggled with it for a while and have my doubts so I'm keen to get feedback on my implementation.
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            BottomSheetView<Test>(options: [Test(name: "hi", type: 7)], selectedOptionsCompletion: {value in})
            BottomSheetView<Test2>(options: [Test2(name: "hi again", type: "7")], selectedOptionsCompletion: {value in})
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct BottomSheetView<T: ListItem>: View  {
    var options: [T]
    var selectedOptionsCompletion: ((T.DataType) -> Void)?
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
            ForEach(options) {item in
                Text(item.name).onTapGesture {
                    let _ = print(type(of: item.type))
                    selectedOptionsCompletion!(item.type)
                }
            }
        }
        .presentationDetents([.medium, .fraction(0.15)])
        .presentationDragIndicator(.hidden)
        .padding()
    }
}

protocol ListItem: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID {get}
    var name: String { get set}
    associatedtype DataType
    var type: DataType { get set}
}
struct Test: ListItem {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    var type: Int
    init(name: String, type: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
    }
}
struct Test2: ListItem {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    var type: String
    init(name: String, type: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
    }
}

